# Personal Reminder with Speak capability repeats multiple times

Tags: functions, dynamic, sound

I am trying to create a personal reminder for myself using the Speak function in Mathematica hoping that the computer speaks the task only once at the designated time. However, I have found that the note is played five times before ending. Is there a way to ensure that the note is spoken once. Kindly find the code below:

```
Reminder[association_] := 
Module[{keys = association // Keys, vals = association // Values},
If[Flatten@# != {} , Speak[ToString@(vals[[Flatten@#]])], ""] &@Position[keys, (DateString[]//DateObject)] ]

Dynamic[{Reminder[Association[(StringSplit["2016-2-2-19-14-40", "-"] // 
    ToExpression // DateObject) -> "30 minutes remaining for incubation",
(StringSplit["2016-2-2-20-46-20", "-"] //ToExpression//DateObject) -> "20 minutes
remaining for incubation"]], Clock[{1, 1}, 1]}]
```

Comment: Have you considered something simpler, such as `RunScheduledTask[Speak["Test"]; RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {0}, AbsoluteTime[] + 5 (* seconds *)]` ?

Comment: Interesting, I will look into what you have written. I am interested in why the message is played more than once with the code that i have posted. any suggestions?

Comment: I have a list of tasks and i really do not have an idea why it repeats even if i try to replace my current code with yours